# how to handle this particular popup..this occurs only in firefox

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit4, browser-automation

[image]I am doing an automation learning project in this web site. https://www.shoppersstop.com/ and when using selenium Firefox browser, i got this particular popup.. i tried with firefox options to block it, but thats not working,, any help is appreciated...

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "src\\test\\resources\\drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
FirefoxOptions Options = new FirefoxOptions();
Options.addPreference("dom.disable_beforeunload", true);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(Options);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);][1]][1]
```

Comment: Could you share your Firefox version and OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable this with profile properties:

```
FirefoxOptions Options = new FirefoxOptions();
Options.addPreference("dom.disable_beforeunload", true);
final FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("geo.enabled", false);
profile.setPreference("geo.provider.use_corelocation", false);
profile.setPreference("geo.prompt.testing", false);
profile.setPreference("geo.prompt.testing.allow", false);
options.setProfile(profile);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(Options);
```